# ODL - Toaster example - DataTreeChangeListener - Can I intercept GETs/READs?

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-restconf

I have been following the steps for the "Toaster" example for OpenDaylight.

At https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step#Part_3:_Add_some_configuration_data_-_My_toast_is_too_light.21 - I can use "DataTreeChangeListener" to intercept WRITEs and DELETEs.

However can I intercept GETs/READs too?

Answer (score 0):

A DataTreeChangeListener doesn't actually intercept WRITEs and DELETEs - it is passively notified after the write/delete operation completes.

There is no mechanism to hook into the read path. But why would you want to and what would it mean to "intercept" a read?